# Is it safe to upload photos of ID to Vikey.it as required by an airbnb host for self check-in

Tags: italy, check-in, airbnb

I have booked an airbnb in Rome. I didn’t notice that it was listed as self check-in. After booking, I received a link to a vikey.it form which asks for a lot of sensitive information as well as photos of all guests’ IDs and photos of guests holding their ID. Should I trust this 3rd party company? I’m concerned about data breaches and identity theft. Surely this could be handled through airbnb, a platform I have decided to trust.

My understanding is that this Vikey.it check in system integrates via an app (nfc) with a Vikey lock on the property. Perhaps there is no way to continue with the booking if I don’t agree to upload the info and photos. Is this worth the risk?

Comment: I would trust a European-based company more than a US based one, but that's not saying much. I would do it.

Comment: I usually only upload my own ID and don't upload the IDs of my guests - it works just fine, as the hosts don't really care.

Comment: It's hard to see how this question can be factually answered as it stands. Unless Vikey have been convicted of fraud, in which case the answer is "no", but that does not seem to be the case. Only you know if it's worth the risk to you. You could ask if it's standard (it varies), or if AirBnB will validate you (nope), or what protections you have.

Comment: If you have to upload your photo with an ID to a site you do not trust I suggest to add a watermark to prevent any reuse. A manual writing (you can also use a brush in a photo editing tool) with the date and the name of the receiver would be safer.